# GeoServer and GeoPackage through WFS

Tags: geoserver, wfs, geopackage

Are there any options to download a GeoPackage from GeoServer through WFS service?

I understand WFS output formats, but I can't find documentation about providing the GeoPackage format.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [install](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/geopkg/installing.html) the [geopackage community module](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/geopkg/) as explained in the [documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/index.html). You can then [request WFS responses](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/geopkg/output.html#geopackage-wfs-output-format) in the `geopackage` format.

Comment: Mind it's a community module and, as such, unsupported. I believe that in order to have it run you'll also need to install the WPS extension (because the module in question contains among others a WPS output format).